# Example pointer in C not working

Tags: c

i'm new learning C, and learning pointer right now,i study from this website, but this code give me an error : pointer.c: In function ‘main’:
pointer.c:6:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Address: %d",&var);  //Notice, the ampersand(&) before var.

i compile it with :  gcc -o pointer pointer.c

```
/* Example to demonstrate use of reference operator in C programming. */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int var = 5;
printf("Value: %d\n",var);
printf("Address: %d",&var);  //Notice, the ampersand(&) before var.
return 0;
}
```

http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers

Comment: Use %p for printing pointer values.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should indent your code.

Comment: yes its working. :) thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to print the address of `var` as if it was a signed integer, which it isn't. It's a pointer, and might have a different size than an integer.

Passing values of mismatching types to `printf()` invokes undefined behavior, which is why the compiler is issuing a friendly warning.

You should use `%p` to format it, and cast the value to `(void *)` to comply with the C standard:

```
printf("Address: %p\n", (void *) &var);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use correct [format specifiers](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_30.htm) for each data type. Addresses are specified by %p.

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you use %p to print a pointer. From the specification:

> p The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner.

Don't forget the cast: `printf("Address: %p\n",(void*)&var);`